# R: Array changing type in a loop

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop, types

I have created a 3D-array and want to fill it with data from two other data.frames

Those data.frames have different colnames and rownames, so sometimes a NULL will pop out when I address a non-existent cell. Both data.frames have a list of 'lm' output in their cells.

But the problem is I keep getting this error:

```
Error in diff_models[i, j, "cont"] <- cont : 
  incorrect number of subscripts
```

I have also noticed that upon creation "diff_models" is a logical type (also strange, btw), but when the error pops out it becomes a list. So I guess the problem is about there being no [i,j,'cont'] in a list. But why does the loop change the type of "diff_models"?

```
cont_col <- colnames(temp1)
cont_row <- rownames(temp1)
dis_col <- colnames(temp2)
dis_row <- rownames(temp2)
cols <- unique(c(cont_col,dis_col))
rows <- unique(c(cont_row,dis_row))

diff_models <- array(NA, c(length(rows),length(cols),2), dimnames = 
                       list('predictor'=rows,'response'=cols, 'condition'=c('dis','cont')))

for (j in cols) {
  for (i in rows) {
    cont <- cont_models[i,j]
    dis <- dis_models[i,j]
    diff_models[i,j,"dis"] <- ifelse(is.null(dis),NA,dis)
    diff_models[i,j,"cont"] <- ifelse(is.null(cont),NA,cont)
  }
}
```

Using

```
diff_models[i][j]["dis"] <- ifelse(is.null(dis),NA,dis)
diff_models[i][j]["cont"] <- ifelse(is.null(cont),NA,cont)
```

does not end up in an error but turns "diff_models" into an empty list.

Saving numerics into the array, however, work perfectly well

Comment: Without looking into details or whether your general approach makes sense: Don't use ifelse as a shortcut for if and else. It's not the same and serves a completely different purpose.

Comment: @Roland
There is nothing wrong with ifelse. The problem is still there if I use

`if (!(is.null(dis))) {
          diff_models[i,j,"dis"] <- dis}`

instead

Comment: There might be other problems in your code (sorry, no reproducible example means we can't investigate this), but your assertion that there is "nothing wrong with [your use of] ifelse" is wrong.

Comment: @Roland
I solved it. Turns out, I can't easily write lists into NA-filled array.
I need to specify there is an empty list in every cell first.

Still no idea why array turns into a list though.